# Cut a field in GridView with Eval and Substring

Tags: asp.net, gridview, eval

I have this field in my gridview:

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="230px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="left" HeaderText="Die neusten 5 RPGs:">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink CssClass="linkWithoutBorder" ID="linkNewRPGUsername"  
             NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("RPGID","~/RPG/Nested/RPGDesc.aspx?type=In&id={0}") %>'
             runat="server"><%# Eval("Name") %>
        </asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Now i wanna have cuttet it on 25 chars whenever it is over 25 chars - how to?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```
<%#Eval("Name").ToString().Length>=25?Eval("Name").ToString().Substring(0,24):Eval("Name").ToString() %>
```

instead of

```
<%# Eval("Name") %>
```

Comment: To check the substring second parameter, you can also use Math.Min:  `Eval("Name").ToString().Substring(0, Math.Min(Eval("Name").ToString().Length, 25))`

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<%#Eval("Name").ToString().Substring(0,24) %>
```

instead of

```
<%#Eval("Name").ToString().Length>=25 Eval("Name").ToString().Substring(0,24):Eval("Name").ToString() %>
```